# Theme not displaying correctly on any page but the homepage.

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I am on Magento 2.2.5 and have been working on it for a few months. I wanted to remove some links on the customer account page so I added-

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-customer-balance-link" remove="true"/>
```

To my default.xml. After running static content deploy and flushing the cache I came back and the only page that looked correct was the homepage. Everything else had the Luma theme, which is my parent theme. I immediately reverted the change but the issue is still there.

When I looked at the source code I noted the var require in the header was different. On the homepage which is correct it says-

var require = {
        "baseUrl": "http://example.com/static/version1536251682/frontend/name/name/en_US"
    };
On every other page it says-

var require = {
        "baseUrl": "http://example.com/static/version1536251682/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US"
    };

Why would these be different? How can I make them the same?

Answer (score 1):

I went in and switched all of my themes to Luma, ran static content deploy, and flushed the cache. All pages had Luma. I did the same thing with my child theme and it came back.